# Story about AI that develops Thank You cards

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I've just heard a brief discussion about a story of an AI developed to write Thank You cards, that then figures out the internet exists and bad stuff happens. I have not been able to find the story anywhere. Can you name it?

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but very much in the same vein (a real news story, no less): http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2016/03/24/microsofts-teen-girl-ai-turns-into-a-hitler-loving-sex-robot-wit/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's the example story in [the long essay at *Wait But Why* about the dangers of AI](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/01/artificial-intelligence-revolution-2.html). Search for "I wrote a little story to show you" to find the specific story, or read from [part 1](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/01/artificial-intelligence-revolution-1.html) for the entire argument.

Comment: That's the story they were relating thanks.